# Ms Sql: query with multiple row criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Cl 
(
  PropId int, 
  ClId int
);
INSERT INTO Cl
(PropId, ClId)
VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(3, 1),
(4, 1),
(4, 2),
(5, 1),
(5, 2);

PropId  ClId
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        2
3        1
4        1
4        2
5        1
5        2
```

I would like to build a query that returns:

```
PropId
2
4
5
```

when in my "WHERE" condition I have only PropId=2. The table join must be through ClId values. Thanks in advance. [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/76bb2/1/0)

Comment: The easiest way would be `where PropId in (2, 4, 5)`, but you might have a different type of logic that you are looking for.  That logic should be in the question.

Comment: Seems, you made some mistake: instead of `PropId=2`, you wanted to say: `CiId=2`. Am i right?

Comment: Thank you for your responce. I have only 2 in my PropId and first of all I have to go to the CliId values and according to them (values and their segmentations) acchive my PropId output. Sorry about unclear explanation.

Comment: Why was this question upvoted?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, who knows?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  Here is one method:

```
select propid
from c1
group by propid
having sum(case when clid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when clid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       count(distinct clid) = 2;
```

Comment: Gordon, OP has added a reply to my comment to the question. Please, read it. Take a look at my answer too.

Answer (score 0):

As to the comment to the question:

> (...) I have only 2 in my `PropId` and first of all I have to go to the `CliId`
>   values and according to them (values and their segmentations) achive
>   my `PropId` output. (...)

If by `segmentation` you mean a set of records that count is equal or greater than 1, you need to join data this way:

```
SELECT C.PropId 
FROM Cl C INNER JOIN (
    SELECT B.ClId 
    FROM Cl B
    WHERE B.PropId = 2
    ) D ON D.Clid = C.Clid
GROUP BY C.PropID
HAVING COUNT(c.ClId )>1
```

Note: The result will be: `{1, 2, 4, 5}`. Why? 
Because a `D` subquery returns set of `ClId`: `{1, 2}` and there's 4 `PropId` records which meet criteria.

Comment: thank you so much for you help and explanation. By "segmentation" I mean exact match in ClId column records. The "1" result of the query is excess because of additional "3" value in ClId column with PropId 1. Is there any way to change you query in order to reach this condition? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excact match is: `Clid={1,2,3,4,5}`. I can't get your logic. Take a look at your data.